# how to make this js more simple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i've js code to appearing page in site like this

```
 //PAGE ABOUT
 $('nav ul.nav-menu li a#about-content').on("click", function() {
     $('section.content').not('content-about').removeClass('active')
     $('section.content.content-about').addClass('active');        
 });

 //PAGE PORTFOLIO
 $('nav ul.nav-menu li a#portfolio-content').on("click", function() {
     $('section.content').not('content-portfolio').removeClass('active')
     $('section.content.content-portfolio').addClass('active');        
 });

 //PAGE BLOG
 $('nav ul.nav-menu li a#blog-content').on("click", function() {
     $('section.content').not('content-blog').removeClass('active')
     $('section.content.content-blog').addClass('active');        
 });

 //PAGE CONTACT
 $('nav ul.nav-menu li a#contact-content').on("click", function() {
     $('section.content').not('content-contact').removeClass('active')
     $('section.content.content-contact').addClass('active');        
 });
```

Could you help me to make this code simpler?

Comment: firstly, remove `nav ul.nav-menu li a` from all your selectors, as you are selecting an element by ID at the end of each selector ... as ID's **must** be unique in a document, the prefix you are using is redundant

Comment: Give the elements an ID for example `id="about"` - `portfolio` then in your onclick function get the use the elements ID to set selectors. `not('content-'+ElementID)` and `$('section.content.content-'+ElementID).addClass` this way you can have one function run for all those elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly simple as is. The best you I think you could really do is write a single function:

```
function handleClick(className) {
  $('section.content').not(className).removeClass('active');
  $('section.content.' + className).addClass('active');
}
```

You can also change `.on('click', cb)` to `.click(cb)`, and as @Jaromanda X mentioned above, you can select directly on ID since IDs must be unqiue.

```
// PAGE ABOUT
$('#about-content').click(handleClick('content-about');

//PAGE PORTFOLIO
$('#portfolio-content').click(handleClick('content-portfolio'));

//PAGE BLOG
$('#blog-content').click(handleClick('content-blog'));

//PAGE CONTACT
$('#contact-content').click(handleClick('content-contact'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as simple as it gets

Firstly, removed all the `nav ul.nav-menu li a` from each selector, as an ID is unique

```
$('#about-content,#portfolio-content,#blog-content,#contact-content').on("click", function() {
    var base = this.id.split('-')[0];
    $('section.content').not('content-' + base ).removeClass('active');
    $('section.content.content-' + base).addClass('active');
});
```

> Note: if your ID's are not unique, jQuery seems to handle that to some degree at least - but I'd recommend you do not have duplicate ID's at all, ever :p